# Kotlin android BottomSheet when I resume app a BottomSheet is change size

Tags: android, kotlin

This is how I init bottom sheet:

```
private fun initBottomSheet() {
    llBottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.sheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior= BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet)
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(object : BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {}
        override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float) {

            val upperState = 0.66
            val lowerState = 0.33
            if (bottomSheetBehavior.state == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_SETTLING) {
                if (slideOffset >= upperState) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
                }
                if (slideOffset > lowerState && slideOffset < upperState) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HALF_EXPANDED
                }
                if (slideOffset <= lowerState) {
                    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED
                }
            }
        }

    })
    changeSize()
}


private fun changeSize() {
    val screenHeight = getScreenHeight(this)
    bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = (screenHeight * 0.2).toInt()

    val params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = llBottomSheet.layoutParams
    params.height = (screenHeight * 0.8).toInt()
    llBottomSheet.layoutParams = params
}
```

And I have a problem. I have a bottom sheet to 1/3 size of phone and  when I lock a phone and later when I resume my app a  bottom sheet go to down or go to up

edit Here i put my `main_xml` in which I include `bottomSheetBehavior` into `sheet_map.xml` file

sheet_map

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="85dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/temp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10sp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_find_connection"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bt_state"
                    android:text="@string/find_connection"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_19" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_find_connection">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/user_info_panel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
                            android:layout_width="50sp"
                            android:layout_height="50sp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0sp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                            android:layout_weight="3.5">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_19"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_user_mail"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_name"
                                android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_16" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
                            android:layout_width="50sp"
                            android:layout_height="50sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_active_tickets"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/user_info_panel"
                        android:text="@string/active_tickets"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_tutorial"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_12" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/list_tickets"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_active_tickets" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500sp"
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_behavior"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="85dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nsv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/temp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:padding="10sp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_find_connection"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/bt_state"
                    android:text="@string/find_connection"
                    android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_19" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/bt_find_connection">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/user_info_panel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_photo"
                            android:layout_width="50sp"
                            android:layout_height="50sp"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="0sp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="5sp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                            android:layout_weight="3.5">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_user_name"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_19"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tv_user_mail"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_user_name"
                                android:textColor="@color/background_tutorial"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_16" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_settings"
                            android:layout_width="50sp"
                            android:layout_height="50sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_active_tickets"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/user_info_panel"
                        android:text="@string/active_tickets"
                        android:textColor="@color/text_color_tutorial"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_dp_12" />

                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/list_tickets"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_active_tickets" />


                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

main xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/sheet_map" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I edit my post and reneme bottomSheet to bottomSheetBehavior

Comment: Add also your `xml` layout

Comment: @Boken I edit my post

Comment: There is some mix with naming. In code you are using `R.id.sheet`, but in attached layout there is not such id. Inside `initBottomSheet()` you have `bottomSheet= BottomSheetBehavior`, but in second method you have name `bottomSheetBehavior`. Are sure that you are not setting anything in lifecycle callback methods like `onPause` or `onResume`?

Comment: @Boken I rename bottomSheet to BottomSheetBehavior and I do not override onPause  and onResume

Comment: @kikiKala2 did you solve the issue? I have similar problem now